# 各教科の中から一番点数のいい点を抽出する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
@english = Point.where(subject: english).order(subject_point: "DESC").first
@japaneese = Point.where(subject: japanese).order(subject_point: "DESC").first
```

と、各科目を条件に点数の高い順に並び替えて、最初のデータを抽出するというやり方しか思いつきません。
各科目を個別に抽出せず、一度に抽出できるやり方などないでしょうか。

Comment: やりたいことがいまいち分からないので確認させてください。教科がいくつかあって、それぞれの教科についてそれぞれの最高点を出したいが、これを各教科に対して1行1行コードを書くのではなく、繰り返しなどを使って簡潔に書きたい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: おっしゃるとおりです。そのやり方をどう実装していいのか、格闘中です。

Comment: その場合、結果を格納する変数は如何なさるのでしょうか。連想配列で良いですか？

Comment: 配列よりハッシュの方がいいかなと思っています。

Comment: 「連想配列」と Ruby の「ハッシュ」は同じもののことです。

Comment: ほしいのは`subject_point`の値だけでしょうか。他のカラムにもアクセスする必要があるのでしょうか。

Comment: そうです、欲しいのは点数のカラムのみです。他のカラムもとる場合、少し考えてみます。

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecordはSQLを隠蔽してくれますが、SQLの知識がないとActiveRecordでどう書いたらいいかわからないとか、典型的にバッドプラクティスとされるようなコードを書いてしまうとか、そういうことになります。結局SQLやデータベースの知識は必要です。

値がほしいだけなら、SQLで書くと

```
SELECT subject, max(subject_point) FROM points GROUP BY subject
```

こうなります。SQLではごく初歩になります。これがわかればActiveRecordで`GROUP BY`やら`max`がどう書けるかを考えればよいので、

```
subject_points = Point.group(:subject).maximum(:subject_point)
subject_points["english"]
```

こういう風にしてとれることがわかります。

最大値を含む行の他のレコード全体を取得したい場合、SQL自体が複雑になりますので、これをActiveRecordで書くのも面倒になります。とはいえFAQの類いなので情報はたくさんあります。興味があれば調べてみてください。

「同じ問い合わせをパラメータを変えてループで回す」というのが典型的なバッドプラクティスの例です。SQLをベースに考えるとそもそもループということが（簡単には）出来ないので、ループで回すようなコードは何かおかしい、という考え方が出来るようになります。

Comment: 裏でのコードを意識、すごく勉強になりました。
確かにform_forとかも裏でどういうHTMLが動いているか、そんなに意識したことありませんでした。
SQLベースで考えたら、確かに同じ処理を条件変えてループする、というのはおかしいですね。
今回は最終的に、レコード全体を取得したいことになりました。
まだまだ、勉強がたりません。